# which one is better Generics or not Generics in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I was wondering if I have the following ArrayList with Generics in Java:

```
   int s=0;
    ArrayList<Integer> items=new ArrayList();
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        items.add(i);
    }
    for (int j=0;j<items.size();j++){
        s=s+items.get(j);
    }
```

or is better to use this raw form?

```
    List listitem=new ArrayList();
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        listitem.add(i);
    }
    for (int j=0;j<listitem.size();j++){
        s=s+(int)listitem.get(j);
    }
    System.out.println(s);
```

I mean I have read that when one use Generics arises the problem of the unboxing and boxing of the variable, that is to change from one primitive type to an object. So which one would be recommended? and in what case generics would be an optimal choose?

Thanks

Comment: The boxing happens in the raw form too.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html

Answer (score 9):

You should almost *never* use the raw form in modern Java. There are a few places where it's hard not to, but in general it's a bad idea.

Using the raw `List` and `ArrayList` types in your second snippet in no way prevents boxing - it just reduces type safety. In the generic version, you don't need the cast to `int` because the compiler *knows* that the list must only contain `Integer` references or null values; in the raw form there's no compile-time guarantee. There's nothing to stop you adding a completely different kind of reference - e.g. a string - to the list.

Answer (score 3):

> I have read that when one use Generics it arises the problem of the unboxing and boxing of the variable, change from one primitive type to an object.

False. You do autoboxing and autoinboxing in both examples; it has nothing to do with generics but with using a primitive in a situation that requires an object.

The generics version is better because it checks that you are not adding objects of unexpected types to the list.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, generics are always better as you can be more certain that your code will work as expected, as incorrect typing can then be spotted by the compiler. For example:

```
List rawList = new ArrayList();
rawList.add(new Integer(2));
rawList.add("Howdy");
for(int i = 0; i < rawList.size(); i++)
{
    String listItem = (String) rawList.get(i); //java.lang.ClassCastException on 0
}
```

The above code compiles but will cause an exception at runtime due to the incorrect casting, however the following code will not compile and prevents you from making this kind of mistake:

```
List<String> gernericList = new ArrayList<>();
gernericList.add(new Integer(2)); //Compiler error: no suitable method found for add(Integer)
gernericList.add("Howdy");
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use generics so that  you can avoid unexpected runtime exception which occur due to casting, since with out generics you can store different objects in a same collection

Answer (score 0):

In both cases boxing and unboxing is happening on your example, always that you use data structures objects will be used, so the conversion to primitive types will ocurr. You could take a look to classes like MutableInteger that avoid the program having to create an object on every iteration since the primitive type is handled as an attribute of the Object.